# Horizontal scrollable slider with visible overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make touch horizontal slider but with visible overflow.
Slider will be located in responsive container with fixed padding, but of course variable width using media queries and margin left and right set to auto. Just like container in bootstrap for example.

First problem is overflow-x, i can just set width of some slider to 100vw and play somehow with left margin of first item. Then see overflow in x axis. But how can I play with this margin if it is non-constant value?

Second problem - elements in this slider has shadow box. With overflow-x: scroll, shadow is not visible in y axis. It would be easier if I had some space for this shadow, but I do not. There is a text needed right above this slider, so I need to make it visible without big padding.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D79Z8.jpg) is how I want slider to look like on start, middle and the end of scrolling.

https://jsfiddle.net/qhf6xzs2/ - here you can see problem with shadow

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.slider {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="margin: 0">Text text text</h1>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think it would be possible for me to solve only one of this problem using some bad practices, but I do not know how to do them at the same time.

UPD: Also, I'm not going to do this using touch event and translate3d, because there will be no momentum after swiping with your finger, items will just stop where you left them. And making this momentum by yourself is pretty complicated task as far as I know. But if I am wrong and it is really easy to implement then please write about how I can do it.

Comment: **Why** didn't you paint those scrollbars in your sketch? As soon as you paint scrollbars to your design you'll know what is the issue. You either want browser's scrollbars or custom ones.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I understand why it is happening. I didn't draw scrollbars because it is just schematic to show desired result.

Comment: No. Draw those scrollbars in your sketch. That way you'll not get answers where people suggest browser scrollbars. - Or perhaps you'll realize (in the process) that it actually cannot be done. Since you **cannot** tell the browser to draw scrollbars narrower that an overflow area. - Well, unless you don't need scrollbars - or you want to use JS to create custom ones. Your question is tagged [html] + [css], not [javascript]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `overflow: hidden` example.
Clearly you need a plugin now to touch-scroll the inners, but this should bet you started as an initial solution - since you marked the question as [css] [html]

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

body * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
  </div>
</div>
```